# Render sidebar based on model in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I started with learning EmberJS and maybe the answer is trivial, but after some researching, I still can't find a solution.
In my model template, I have some buttons(each for the different object) which after click should expand sidebar with its details.

What do I want to reach is something like this:

[image: EXAMPLE SCREENSHOT]

Could someone provide me with some simple twiddle?

Comment: could you provide some code that you have tried ?

Comment: show us what you've tried here https://ember-twiddle.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this effect.

## Using controller's variable

```
{{#foreach model as |obj|}}
  <button onclick={{action (mut activeModel) obj}}>{{obj.name}}</button>
{{/foreach}}
<!--Somewhere later in template-->
{{#if activeModel}}
  <!--Code of overlay and sidebar, close button sets activeModel to undefined-->
{{/if}}
```

## Using child (nested) route

Parent template:

```
{{#foreach model as |obj|}}
  {{#link-to 'parentRoute.childRoute' obj tagName="button"}}
    {{obj.name}}
  {{/link-to}}
{{/foreach}}
<!--Somewhere later in template-->
{{outlet}}
```

Child template should contain code of overlay and sidebar, close button redirects back to parent route

Answer (score 0):

well, one of the options is that you can **create components** and **pass the modified model**(modify the model using onclick function) as the data to that component.

for example,

let us just say that this is your **main template**

```
<button onclick="changeSideBar()">click</button>
<div style="display:none; //render it in the left-half(using bootstrap models)">
     {{sidebar-component model=model.modified}}
</div>
```

in the **javascript code (component.js)**,

```
function changeSideBar()
{
    var modified= ;//set as per your convienince by iterating actual models or by any means
    this.set('model.modified',modified);
    //make display of sidebar div "block"
}
```

**sidebar-component** is your component. make the component as per your wish.

hope it helps.

I can't help much without your templates or codes. It would be great if you provide some of your works.